# Find Shortest element in Array

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a Array

```
string[] names = { "Jim Rand", "Barry Williams", "Nicole Dyne", "Peter Levitt", "Jane Jones", "Cathy Hortings"};
```

Is there any way to find which is the shortest(Length wise) element in this array and then store rest of elements in a different array.

Thanks,
Ani

Comment: What language are you using ?

Comment: @ereOn: the syntax seems to be C#. but still, a language tag would definitely be more called for than any of the current tags.

Comment: @Nayan: Thanks but I asked *before* the tag was set ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
var orderedNames = names.OrderBy(name => name.Length);

string shortestName = orderedNames.First();

string[] otherNames = orderedNames.Skip(1).ToArray();
```

Comment: Note that this will be inefficient for large arrays; sorting the array requires O(n lg n) comparisons. There is an algorithm to solve this problem that is O(n).  I also note that you sort the list *twice* in your solution. Calling First() orders the list. Calling Skip *sorts the original list again*. Remember, LINQ doesn't know that you haven't changed "names" on another thread between the calls; the answer might be different so the result has to be recomputed.

Comment: @Eric Lippert: ah yes, good point. adding `.ToList()` in the original assignment to `orderedNames` should remedy that last issue, right?

Comment: Yes, though then you have the problem that you are *copying* the same data twice; once to a list that is only useful for its first element, and then to the shorter array.

Answer (score 2):

In C#, .Net 3.5:

```
string shortestName = names.Aggregate((n1, n2)=>n1.Length<n2.Length?n1:n2);
```

This is how you can store other elements in other array

```
var otherArrays = names.Exclude(new List<string>(){shortestName});
```

Comment: +1. I love how C# made such a thing so simple ;) However you're missing the second part of the question which demands to store the others elements in an array.

Comment: that gives you the length of the shortest item, tho; it doesn't tell you which item that is

Comment: Thanks a lot, I am new never tried this code..I ll try...Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

There is no `.Exclude` method (or extension method) for an Array and he didn’t say that he wanted to change the collection type for the new Array.  Your use of the `.Aggregate` is outstanding so let’s take it one step further and use `.Aggregate` to do the excluding as well!

Like this:

```
string shortestName = names.Aggregate((n1, n2) => n1.Length < n2.Length ? n1 : n2);
string nonArrayString = names.Aggregate((n1, n2) => n2 != shortestName ? n1 + " " + n2 : n1);
string[] newNames = nonArrayString.Split(' ');
```

David Hedlund’s technique is still far better because it’s easier to read!  There are no bonus points for writing the most complicated answer... lol